# Compare two files in two different folders and perofrm installation of that file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script which compares two files in two different folders. If a file with the proper number exists in the first folder then it runs it.

If the file doesn't exist in the first folder then it copies it from the second folder to the first folder and runs it from the first folder.

```
function Invoke-InstallationOfANewBuild()
{
    param (
        $ptud = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\",
        $ptbf = "\\r\P\Al\O\D B\R 017\x64"
    )

    begin { 
        $output1 = Get-ChildItem $ptbf -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
                No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
                Name = $_.FullName
            } 
        } | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1

        $output2 = Get-ChildItem $ptbf -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
                No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
                Name = $_.FullName 
            } | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 
        }

        Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $output1 -DifferenceObject $output2
    }

    process { 

        if ($LASTEXITCODE = 0)
        { 
            Get-ChildItem $ptud -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
                New-Object psobject -Property @{
                    No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
                    Name = $_.FullName
                }

            } | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | Foreach { & $_ -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=standalone -UpdateMaterials=yestoall -UpgradeDBIfRequired=yes" }
        }
        else
        {
            Get-ChildItem  $ptbf -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
                New-Object psobject -Property @{
                    No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
                    Name = $_.FullName
                }

            } | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | Copy-Item -Destination $ptud | Foreach { & $_ -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=standalone -UpdateMaterials=yestoall -UpgradeDBIfRequired=yes" }
        }
    } 

    end { return $LASTEXITCODE }
}
```

I have a problem in the `else` block - file copies from the second folder to the first folder but the file execution is not started.

Also I am looking for better solution with `if` block. I want to say - if operation `Compare-Object` returns `true` than start everything in `if` block, if operation returns `false` (for example file with such doesn't exist in 1st folder) -than start everything in `else` block.

Comment: `if ($LASTEXITCODE = 0)` => `if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)` assuming that logic even works there. Equals is an assignment operator not a comparison.

Comment: `$LASTEXITCODE` of what? I don't see you invoking any external executables in the script?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Pls refer to last part of my message.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how `$LASTEXITCODE` works - it's an automatic variable that get's updated whenever and *external program is run from within powershell*, with the exit code of that program.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for clarification. I guess I should use `$?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your compare try this:

```
$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $A -DifferenceObject $B | 
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } | 
        Measure-Object -Property inputObject
$compare.count -gt 0 # for your if condition
```

for your copy-object problem, try this:
the Tee-Object wil duplicate the pipeline to a variable

```
Get-ChildItem  $ptbf -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
                New-Object psobject -Property @{
                    No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
                    Name = $_.FullName
                }

            } | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | Tee-Object -variable Duplicate | Copy-Item -Destination $ptud 
$duplicate | Foreach { & $_ -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=standalone -UpdateMaterials=yestoall -UpgradeDBIfRequired=yes" }
```

Comment: Regarding execution of an `.exe` file - problem not in my cmdlet - it works only if I remove `Copy-Item -Destination $ptud` this part. I can't understand why it happens.

Comment: offcorse, you copy-item doesn' put a item on the pipeline so, the pipeline stops after the copyitem. I'll edit my answer!